# Powered by Text-Enhance?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hyperlinks, advertising

What's up with the links that are attached to seemingly random words that link to advertisements? When you hover over them, it says "Powered Text-Enhance" and shows an ad. There's one in my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13289/489) on the word "below" at the end of the first bullet-point which I certainly did not put there myself. I've found others scattered among other recent questions and answers.

Comment: where do you see it?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, I just added a link, but realized that the ad is not there anymore. Nor in other places that I've seen it and just checked again. It must be some strange thing on the desktop computer that I was using before. (Now I'm using my laptop.) Strange.

Comment: Sounds like it may have been adware on said computer.

Comment: It's a browser plugin.  Remove it!